# Only one field in my form being set php and sql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am coming into an issue in my form when i try to set the value of my field 
to a value of a variable it works exactly how i want it for my product field but nothing is showing up in the price field in my form

any help is appreciated i have benn at it for a good while

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM suplements WHERE product = '$product' OR name = '$prodname' OR price = '$price' OR image = '$image'";
                $result = @mysql_query($query) or die ("could not execute SQL query");


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {          ?>
        <table>
             <tr>
                <th>Product :<?php echo $row["product"]?></th>


            </tr>
                <td><img src = "<?php echo $row["image"] ?>"height="400"                     width="400"><?php ?>
                <td>
                                    <form>
                                        <input type="text" name="qty" value="1" size="2"><br>

                                        Product <input type="text" name="product" value="<?php echo htmlentities($product); ?>" /></br>
                                        Price <input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo htmlentities($price); ?>" />

                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD" >

                                    </form>
                                    <?php echo $row["information"];?></td>



                <tr><td><?php echo $row["product"];?>
                <?php echo $row["name"];?>
                <?php echo $row["drand"];?>
                <?php echo $row["weight"];?>
            <td><?php echo $row["price"];?></td></tr>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: The values including the price are being printed for the other echos just not the one in my form

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Product <input type="text" name="product" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['product']); ?>" /></br>
Price <input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['price']); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For debug sake, do this after the while: "print_r($row);" - this will show you the exact contents of the $row variable

Plus... it would be nice to add limit 1 to your query